# The Absence of Prophets in Islam

Tags: allah, prophets

Similar to how every product has a manual and a person who teaches how to use it, God has also provided us the Quran and the Prophet Muhammad SAW. Now, we have the Quran, but there has been no one after Prophet Muhammad SAW for the last 1400 years. So, my question is: Why has God not sent us more prophets?

Not to change the religion in any way, but because we need someone to lead/show us. If God had sent us more prophets, the Ummah wouldn't be divided this much, and we would be in a better place. It seems as if God is saying, “I have done my job, now good luck,” and does not seem to care. Also, without us Muslims, very few people would be aware of Islam. Why are we supposed to spread Islam if God doesn't do it himself by sending messengers? For instance, after 1400 years, the majority in South and North America still don't even know what Islam is. Not to mention that between Isa a.s. and Muhammad s.a.w. there are 700 years with no prophets.

Also as far as i know in islam there are messengers(Muhammad, Musa, Nuh, Isa etc. a.s.) who Allah sent rules/books and normal prophets who follow their previous messenger's book and teach it to the people. So why hasn't he done this for us, meaning send another prophet after Muhammad s.a.w. to guide us?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confused about this issue. Messengers were sent by Allah(swt), since the people were lost and there was no way for them to be directed. As Allah states in Surah Nasr that Muhammad's (saw) life is fulfilled "When Allah's ʹultimate˺ help comes and the victory ˹over Mecca is achieved˺,"

> 5:3 "This day I have perfected for you your religion and completed My
> favor upon you and have approved for you Islām as religion. "
>
> In another hadith which is sahih
>
> Anas bin Malik narrated: "The Messenger of Allah (s.a.w) said: 'Indeed
> Messenger-ship and Prophethood have been terminated, so there shall be
> no Messenger after me, nor a Prophet.''" (Jami` at-Tirmidhi 2272 higlighted text)
>
> It is certainly We Who have revealed the Reminder, and it is certainly
> We Who will preserve it.

There won't be any prophets after Muhammad (saw) as Islam has been perfected and protected.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I already know the verse and hadith you quoted. At the time of Musa a.s. the torah was perfect for the sons of Israel at that time but God still sent prophets after him(i know it was not preserved like quran but still). But also even though the quran is perfect, why would god not send us more prophets. We still need someone to help guide us. You see how many sects of islam there are and how much people dissagree about many things. Why cant God send prophets every 100 years for example to keep us in the right track. Btw its not my intention to offend anyone.

Comment: @Sulejman It is your doubts that can be disproved; God is knowledgeable in everything that he does, perfect in all that he does, and he knows what you do not know. Your argument is absurd since, as I've already said, we don't really need a messenger.